# Nodejs/electron Override chromium browser timeout.

Tags: node.js, electron, chromium

Been looking all over for this information, closest i can see is the 
command line switches. i have a web page that i ported to electron and im trying to override the Browser inactivity timeout. for example running a report over 2 minutes the browser times out the connection. My thinking for a quick fix was to wrap in electron and extend the browser timeout.

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#timeout
https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/chrome-command-line-switches.md

In Electron the main.js looks to have wrapped the modules in webpack 
in all of the examples ive found

it looks like this

You can use app.commandLine.appendSwitch to append them in your app's main script before the ready event of the app module is emitted:

```
    const { app } = require('electron')
    app.commandLine.appendSwitch('remote-debugging-port', '8315')
    app.commandLine.appendSwitch('host-rules', 'MAP * 127.0.0.1')

   app.on('ready', () => {
     // Your code here
   })
```

however in my electron file my const app is actually

```
   const path = __webpack_require__(14);
   const electron = __webpack_require__(18);
   const unusedFilename = __webpack_require__(20);
   const pupa = __webpack_require__(23);
   const extName = __webpack_require__(24);

   const {app, shell} = electron;
```

i have tried

```
   app.commandLine.appendSwitch("--disable-renderer-backgrounding");
   app.commandLine.appendArgument('--disable-timeouts-for-profiling');
```

Doesnt seem to work, Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not put the heavy lifting in a service worker and do it all asynchronously? Waiting 2 minutes for the window to finish rendering just seems like bad UX.

Comment: Agree completely, this is a quick fix as the devs for the Web app wont have this done in months. issues lie in the database query taking extremely long time.

Comment: Why can't you initiate the database call _after_ the initial page load?

Comment: the database call is what populates the data table that the page will load. it takes over 2 minutes. the app is currently in .net and will be changed over eventually because of that dev changes are not high priority.

Comment: Have your `index.html` use an `XMLHttpRequest` to the page that does the database call. [`XHR`'s don't have a timeout by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/timeout). Then the `index.html` page loads immediately, and doesn't block the main thread. No hacking of Electron required.

Comment: do you get `did-fail-load` with code -7 (timeout) on your `webContents`? If so, you can handle the problem there, too, I believe

Comment: XHR failed loading:is what the console log on chrome states after it times out.